# I can't extract images to the pdf file I created with cshtml

Tags: .net, angular, razor

**I can't take an image to my pdf file with my cshtml in my angular and dotnet project**

***The folder with the image and my cshtml file***
[image]

**The code I use to call my image**

```
<img src="../tca.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
```

I couldn't solve the problem, please help